# Bitmap Memory Management

Tags: android, media-player, out-of-memory

Recently I have been working on a music player for android as a learning experience. It is coming along quite well, but there is one problem. In the music player activity I get the embedded album cover of the song that is playing as a bitmap. I then set this bitmap to an ImageView. This works fine, but after having launched about 10 different songs I get an OutOfMemoryException. This is weird because every time that I start a new song onCreate() is called, which means that onStop() was called in the previous activity (right?), and in onStop I release the bitmap (I also tried onDestroy() but that didn't help). Also if a new song starts playing the media player is reset so that shouldn't be a problem either. So do any of you have suggestions as to why the OutOfMemoryException is occurring?

Comment: are you displaying thumbnails of image or full size image you display in image view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your images in onResume() and recycle the same in onPause(). Also you need to load bitmaps efficiently

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Check the link under the topic Loading scaled down version into memory.

Check the video in the link for memory management

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk.

To find the cause of memory leak use a MAT Analyzer as shown in the above link.

OutOfMemoryException occurs if there is not enough memory in heap for your app.

onCreate() is called once during the activity lifecycle unless the activity is destroyed and you start the activity again onCreate() is not called.

Comment: Great resources! Also, next to that link, try http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html . Also, *can't emphasize enough* how easy it is to snooker yourself into a situation where you need to call recycle() yourself.